# seaborn barplot of grouped data

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, seaborn

This is my dataset:

[image: dataset]

I'd like to use seaborn to plot each column, just like `pandas` would do by default:

[image: plot]

Any clue?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first stack the data, and then use `sns.barplot` with hue:

```
stacks = df.stack().reset_index()

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
sns.barplot(x='level_1', y=0, data=stacks, hue='cat')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]